# Integration by substitution involving trig

Tags: integration

> $$y = \frac{\cos x}{2-\sin x}, 0\le x\le\pi$$
>   Find area of curve bounded by $x$ and $y$ axis, curve and $\pi/6$

I integrated to get

$$\ln(2-\sin x)$$

I found where curve crosses x axis at $\pi/2$ but I cannot get right answer... book says $\ln(4/3)$ thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: When you say "and $\pi/6$", do you mean the line $x=\pi/6$ or the line $y=\pi/6$? Also, your integration should give a $-$ sign outside the $\ln$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Note that $-\ln(2-\sin(x))|_0^{\pi/6} = \ln(4/3)$.

Comment: Right. Yes I mean x = pi/6. Math lover, why is it minus ln? And is the curve bound between x = 0 And pi/6? And not when it crosses axes?

Comment: @user489915 $\int \frac{\cos(x)}{2-\sin(x)} dx = \color{red}{-} \ln(2-\sin(x)) + c$.

Answer (score 1):

You are close with your integral - you just need to substitute the values in. (Also you have a minus sign missing).

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{\cos x}{2-\sin x}\,\mathrm dx=\int_{\text{some limits}} \frac{1}{2-u}\,\mathrm du$$where we used the substitution $u=\sin x$. 
$$I=\left[-\ln (2-\sin x)\right]_0^{\pi/6}=[-\ln(2-\tfrac12)]-[-\ln(2-0)]=\ln2-\ln\tfrac32=\ln\left(2\cdot\frac23\right)\\\implies I=\ln\left(\frac43\right)$$

---

I notice you asked why it is $-\ln(2-u)$ in the comments - this is because on the bottom of the fraction you have inside the integral, the $u$ has a negative sign in front, so $$\frac d{du}(2-u)=-1$$ As a result, when you differentiate $\ln(2-u)$, you would end up with $$\frac{1}{2-u}\cdot\frac d{du}(2-u)=-\frac{1}{2-u}$$ which is not what we integrated to start with.

Comment: Right thank you. So when integrating anything with -1 power... integrate with a "1/k" and multiply by ln? E.g. 1/5x would be 0.2ln5x. Or the differential of k I should say. Also why is the integral to zero?

Comment: To your first sentence - yep exactly. Why is the integral to $0$? Because the question says "bounded by the y-axis", and the y-axis **is** the line $x=0$ - so the integral over $x$ starts at $0$.